# Как скрыть надпись (Скрыть меню) в вертикальном меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу спрятать текст внизу, при клике на кнопку (внизу меню). Помогите разобраться.

Меню скачано отсюда:
https://github.com/cbfranca/vertical-responsive-menu

Demo меню: http://cbfranca.github.io/vertical-responsive-menu/demos/demo.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
/* ======  Vertical Responsive Menu ======*/

'use strict';

var tid = setInterval( function () {
  if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;
  clearInterval( tid );


  var querySelector = document.querySelector.bind(document);

  var nav = document.querySelector('.vertical_nav');
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

  var menu = document.getElementById("js-menu");
  var subnavs = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu--item__has_sub_menu');


  // Toggle menu click
  querySelector('.toggle_menu').onclick = function () {

    nav.classList.toggle('vertical_nav__opened');

    wrapper.classList.toggle('toggle-content');

  };


  // Minify menu on menu_minifier click
  querySelector('.collapse_menu').onclick = function () {

    nav.classList.toggle('vertical_nav__minify');

    wrapper.classList.toggle('wrapper__minify');

    for (var j = 0; j < subnavs.length; j++) {

      subnavs[j].classList.remove('menu--subitens__opened');

    }

  };


  // Open Sub Menu
  for (var i = 0; i < subnavs.length; i++) {

    if (subnavs[i].classList.contains('menu--item__has_sub_menu') ) {

      subnavs[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {

        for (var j = 0; j < subnavs.length; j++) {

          if(this != subnavs[j])
            subnavs[j].classList.remove('menu--subitens__opened');
          
        }

        this.classList.toggle('menu--subitens__opened');

      }, false);

    }
  }

}, 100 );
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  /*top: 0;
  left: 0;*/
  z-index: 999;

  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  background: #FE964E;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 -20px 20px 20px;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  /*margin-top: 50px;*/
  padding: 15px 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* Small devices (tablets)
==========================*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {

}


/* Medium devices (desktops)
==========================*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {

  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: none;
  }

  .wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }

  .wrapper__minify {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

}





/*
=========================
Vertical Reponsive Menu
=========================
*/
/* line 6, sass/import/mixins.scss */
.vertical_nav, .collapse_menu .collapse_menu--icon {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out; }

/* line 14, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* line 26, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
:focus,
:active {
  outline: none; }

/* line 32, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.toggle_menu {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer; }
  /* line 44, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .toggle_menu i {
    display: block;
    font-size: 28px; }

/* line 52, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.vertical_nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #f6f6f6; }

/* line 63, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.vertical_nav__closed {
  left: -200px !important; }

/* line 67, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.vertical_nav__opened {
  left: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) -30px 0 30px 30px; }

/* line 73, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none; }

/* line 84, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px; }

/* line 90, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--item__has_sub_menu .menu--link:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f0d7"; }

/* line 100, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--subitens__opened {
  background: #e9e9e9; }
  /* line 103, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .menu--subitens__opened .menu--link {
    color: #000; }
  /* line 107, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .menu--subitens__opened .sub_menu {
    display: block; }

/* line 113, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--link {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer; }
  /* line 123, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .menu--link:hover, .menu--link:hover .menu--label {
    color: #000;
    background: #dddddd; }

/* line 131, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--icon {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px; }

/* line 140, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.menu--label {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px; }

/* line 148, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none; }

/* line 154, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.sub_menu--link {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none; }
  /* line 162, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .sub_menu--link:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #dddddd; }

/* line 168, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.sub_menu--link__active {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500; }

/* line 176, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
.collapse_menu {
  display: none; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  /* line 193, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .vertical_nav {
    left: 0; }

  /* line 197, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .toggle_menu {
    display: none; }

  /* line 203, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .vertical_nav__minify {
    width: 50px; }
    /* line 206, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .menu {
      overflow: visible; }
    /* line 210, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .menu--label {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      padding-right: 16px;
      background: #e9e9e9;
      font-weight: 500; }
    /* line 222, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .menu--item__has_sub_menu .menu--link:after {
      content: ""; }
    /* line 228, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .menu--subitens__opened .menu--label,
    .vertical_nav__minify .menu--subitens__opened .sub_menu {
      display: block; }
    /* line 232, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .sub_menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      background: #e9e9e9; }
    /* line 239, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .sub_menu--link {
      padding-left: 16px; }
    /* line 245, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .vertical_nav__minify .collapse_menu--icon {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }

  /* line 253, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
  .collapse_menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer; }
    /* line 269, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .collapse_menu:hover {
      color: #000;
      background: #dddddd; }
    /* line 274, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .collapse_menu .collapse_menu--icon {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-size: 20px; }
      /* line 282, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
      .collapse_menu .collapse_menu--icon:before {
        content: "\f053"; }
    /* line 288, sass/vertical-responsive-menu.scss */
    .collapse_menu .collapse_menu--label {
      display: block;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px; } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vertical Responsive Menu</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <link href='css/normalize.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="css/vertical-responsive-menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header clearfix">
    <button type="button" id="toggleMenu" class="toggle_menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <h1>Vertical Responsive Menu</h1>
  </header>

  <nav class="vertical_nav">

    <ul id="js-menu" class="menu">

      <li class="menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu">

        <label class="menu--link" title="Item 1">
          <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
          <span class="menu--label">Item 1</span>
        </label>

        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="sub_menu--link sub_menu--link__active">Submenu</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="#" class="sub_menu--link">Submenu</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="#" class="sub_menu--link">Submenu</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu--item">
        <a href="#" class="menu--link" title="Item 2">
          <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i>
          <span class="menu--label">Item 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="menu--item">
        <a href="#" class="menu--link" title="Item 3">
          <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
          <span class="menu--label">Item 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu">

        <label class="menu--link" title="Item 4">
          <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-database"></i>
          <span class="menu--label">Item 4</span>
        </label>

        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="#" class="sub_menu--link">Submenu</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="#" class="sub_menu--link">Submenu</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub_menu--item">
            <a href="#" class="sub_menu--link">Submenu</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu--item">
        <a href="#" class="menu--link" title="Item 5">
          <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i><!-- <img src="checkbox.png" class="menu--icon "> -->
          <span class="menu--label">Item 5</span>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <button id="collapse_menu" class="collapse_menu">
      <i class="collapse_menu--icon  fa fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="collapse_menu--label">Скрыть меню</span>
    </button>

  </nav>


  <div class="wrapper">

    <section>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent fermentum interdum orci in finibus. Cras eu ante condimentum, efficitur libero vitae, rhoncus eros. Curabitur a auctor sem, ac porta metus. Ut volutpat eu neque nec mattis. Nullam viverra sem vitae diam sollicitudin pulvinar. Ut elementum urna non mollis eleifend. Cras maximus rhoncus lacus, vitae pellentesque nunc sodales a. Donec blandit nec odio sit amet porttitor.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vestibulum a est vitae risus porta sollicitudin vitae a neque. Curabitur facilisis risus quis libero viverra aliquet. Vestibulum vehicula elit eget velit vulputate, id bibendum mauris hendrerit. Donec eleifend lorem eu pulvinar feugiat. Cras at feugiat tellus. Ut non orci ac turpis euismod iaculis non at sem. Vestibulum sit amet nulla est. Etiam sodales condimentum tellus, sed auctor diam sagittis et. Suspendisse id orci at lectus scelerisque mattis. Vivamus mollis euismod massa, vitae volutpat nisi commodo et. Donec a tellus nulla. Nunc quis ligula cursus, blandit nulla vitae, ullamcorper neque. Aliquam dictum tempus sem nec dignissim.
      </p>
      <p>
        Fusce luctus lacus a ipsum dapibus pellentesque. Nunc dapibus metus lacinia enim ultrices consequat. Praesent convallis elit sed velit hendrerit congue. Donec aliquam velit et egestas bibendum. Fusce nec urna euismod, tempor eros id, scelerisque diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras diam ex, posuere a tristique sed, efficitur in velit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Duis eu odio dictum arcu consequat tempor nec a neque. Duis ultrices fermentum nulla in interdum. Donec imperdiet bibendum nisl. Donec justo nisl, iaculis nec eleifend sit amet, tincidunt finibus quam. Aenean lobortis tortor ac imperdiet ultrices. Donec a eleifend sem. Praesent vitae lorem faucibus, imperdiet magna vel, mollis dolor. Aenean ut sollicitudin ex. Nullam viverra faucibus ante et pulvinar. Curabitur maximus est sit amet ante elementum sagittis. Aliquam at tempor orci. Nam vel volutpat metus. Quisque semper, enim at fermentum hendrerit, elit leo volutpat nunc, a sagittis nunc urna nec dolor. Praesent lobortis elit dapibus eros suscipit, ut semper lectus fermentum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Curabitur sed mi sapien. Nullam ullamcorper laoreet dui, id fermentum nisl aliquam et. Proin iaculis magna fermentum nisl rutrum cursus. Quisque vitae auctor sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus aliquam, arcu commodo tristique suscipit, risus augue ullamcorper risus, in dapibus libero lacus eu odio. Praesent rutrum suscipit luctus. Pellentesque id erat nibh. Integer vel orci tristique, fermentum leo vitae, tincidunt urna. Suspendisse venenatis metus nisl, non tincidunt orci elementum ut. Curabitur vitae luctus ligula. Nunc consequat eu justo a efficitur. Vivamus eu luctus urna, sit amet aliquam ligula. Nulla euismod purus quis eros volutpat sollicitudin. Cras consequat convallis mi non vehicula.
      </p>
    </section>

  </div>

  <script src="js/vertical-responsive-menu.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте правило .vertical_nav__minify .collapse_menu--label { display: none; }

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо действительно работает, если можете напишите ответ на вопрос.